# How to update two database each other real time WordPress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Thank in advance,
I am facing issue when i am migrating two databases each other in WordPress. I want to update two databases real time when one database table record udpate then other database table will automatically updated. So i need proper solution for it how can i possible this thing in wordpress.

I am having two blog one is for desktop site and another one is for mobile site and i want both blogs are connected each other so if i will enter any blog in mobile site then in desktop site blog automatically updated and also all this things work properly with comments and users.

Comment: Why cant both use same database? With Multisite Network Support. https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/multisite/
Because believe me you will make a headache with solution you are seeking for, if you still want to do this look for Database Replication this article might help you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37015/replicate-some-tables-without-transferring-the-entire-log because you wont need all tables to be replicated.

Comment: Thanks for replay,
I already tried with multi site and multisite will manage users separately. Blog layout is different for mobile and desktop site that's y i have created two child themes. Another issue is that in multisite there are two child theme of single parent theme. That's y i am finding proper solution for it.

Comment: I would go for the same database but code the theme so that you output a different template for the mobile site. You can use mobile detection on php side or allow users to toggle between the version of the site by saving user preferences within the session, for example. You will have only one url, so no duplicate content and might be better for SEO?

Comment: @safik you should still try to use multisite, maybe search for some advanced plugin for multisite or something. Proper solution for this is 100% multisite, you wont find more proper one, everything else will be what we call a "hack".

Comment: @nick I already have two different blog with different layout and functionality so can you please suggest me a proper solution for how can i resolve it.

Comment: @vytsci I already tried with multi site and i am finding proper solution for it. If you have any other idea then please suggest me.

Comment: Ive already suggested other solution in my previous comment.